# SSIS Load CSV with different number of columns on every load

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

We are working on a SSIS job to load the CSV file to a SQL table. This job is to be scheduled for daily load. The problem is this CSV file comes with different columns each day. Structure of the file is as below:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Date</td><td>New York</td><td>Washington</td><td>London</td></tr>
<tr><td>15-04-2020</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>20</td></tr>
<tr><td>16-04-2020</td><td>30</td><td>50</td><td>22</td></tr>
</table>
```

Date column remains the same where as number of columns for city changes based on the data for that day. It could 1 city column or many more city columns. Each city column means the number of likes from the that city on that day.

I am thinking to convert the structure to a 3 column structure including Date, City Name and Number of Likes.

But how would a flat file source component would handle it and how would I transform it to a new structure?

Comment: That does not look like a CSV file contents...

Comment: First of all this is not a CSV!

Comment: I think your 3 column idea is the way to go.  Parse the xml with a script component source and accumulate the likes for each state there, outputting the data in the form you want it

Comment: I think your data normalized looks like this.... City, Date, Amount. Are you receiving HTML or CSV?

Comment: It is just normal csv. I think i incorrectly used the html. I just wanted to create a table there in the question

Answer (score 1):

I will walk you through a script component to handle this:

I am assuming your csv looks like this and not the html above:

```
Date,New York,Washington,London
15-04-2020,2,3,20
16-04-2020,30,50,22
```

I named this file likes.txt and saved it on my D:\

1. Add a dataflow
2. Add a Script Component (Source)
3. Go to inputs and outputs and add your outputs (don't forget data types)
   [image]
4. Go into the script and paste the following Code into CreateNewOutputRows:

   ```
   string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\likes.txt");

   List<string> cities = new List<string>();

   int ctr = 0;
   foreach (string line in lines)
   {
       ctr++;
       //skip empty rows
       if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

       //Get Cities from Header
       if (ctr == 1)//Header row
       {
           string[] headers = line.Split(',');
           for (int i = 1; i < headers.Length; i++)
           {
               cities.Add(headers[i]);
           }
           continue; //Go to next line
       }

       //Work with details
       string[] pieces = line.Split(',');
       for (int i = 1; i < pieces.Length; i++)
       {
           Output0Buffer.AddRow();
           Output0Buffer.City = cities[i-1];
           Output0Buffer.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(pieces[0].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
           Output0Buffer.Likes = int.Parse(pieces[i]);
       }


   }
   ```
5. Add the following namespaces to make the code work:

   ```
     using System.IO;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Globalization;
   ```

Here are your results:
[image]

There's quite a bit to unpack in that script as it uses Lists, Arrays, File System Tasks, etc. Let me know if you have questions.

PS - This is a Corona Virus Answer (meaning I am bored) without any effort on your end. Please at least show what you tried in the future.